# Select model object in cake php 3

Tags: cakephp

I am new to cakePhp. I have two models name Category and SubCategory in CakePHP3. I want to select the object of Category model where id = 2 and related models of SubCategory. Please help me to get the data.

Comment: Use the documentation for these *very basics* http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html or even better, do the quick start and tutorial first.

Answer (score 2):

Use associations and containments, it's well explained in the manual.

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#retrieving-associated-data

Once you've setup the associations, you can simply query for the category and have the associated sub categories included automatically.

```
$query = TableRegistry::get('Categories')
    ->find()
    ->contain(['SubCategories'])
    ->where([
        'id' => 2
    ]);

debug($query->toArray());
```